# Get object from Vuex at specific index

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am getting an array from Vuex and I want an object at 2 positions.

HTML

```
<p class="">
    {{ MainImg[2].para}}
  </p>
```

Vue

```
export default {
name: "App",
components: {  },
data() {
return {
  imageQuery: this.$route.params.image,
};
},
computed: {
...mapGetters("design", {
  MainImg: ["singleDesigns"]
})
},
created() {
this.fetchDesigns();
},
mounted() {
 console.log(this.MainImg);
},

methods: {
fetchDesigns() {
  this.$store.dispatch("design/getSingleDesign", this.imageQuery); 
    }
  }
};
```

But it shows an undefined error.
And When I add MainImg array in Vue data like this.

```
data() {
return {
  imageQuery: this.$route.params.image,
  MainImg:[{para:"1"},{para:"2"},{para:"3"},{para:"4"}]
};
```

It Works.
P.S.-
Store Code-

```
export const state = () => ({
designs: [],
})

export const getters = {
  singleDesigns(state)  {
    return state.designs;
  }
}
```

I am not adding Action and Mutation because it works fine with other code.

Comment: Show `store` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the array is empty at the first rendering, so you should add a condition to render it :

```
<p class="" v-if="MainImg && MainImg.length >= 2">
    {{ MainImg[2].para}}
  </p>
```

Comment: It works but I can't add conditions because my code is very big. And I will have to add it to multiple places.

Comment: How can I populate the array at first rendering?

Comment: It will be populated when it will be full, don't care about the first rendering

Comment: Do I have to add the v-if line every time when using the array?

Comment: You could add it to the component root